# Problem to integrate a tailwindcss / laravel8 form, does not retrieve data and found an error SQLSTATE [23000] Integrity violation: 1048

Tags: laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I have two forms :

One works with the same data and the other don't.

I'm new to laravel and tailwindcss and i need to understand what is happening.

I must have made a mistake that I don't see or understand...

My form 1 : Data passes

```
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <span class="block text-red-500">{{ $error }}</span>
    @endforeach

    <form action="{{ route('categories.posts.store', $category) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <x-label for="title" value="Titre du post" />
        <x-input id="title" name="title" />

        <x-label for="content" value="Contenu du post" />
        <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>

        <x-label for="image" value="Image du post" />
        <x-input type="file" id="image" name="image"/>


        <x-button style="display: block !important" class="mt-10">Créer mon post</x-button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My form 2 : Data don't passes

```
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="bg-white shadow rounded-lg p-6">
        <div class="grid lg:grid gap-6">
            <div class="border focus-within:border-blue-500 focus-within:text-blue-500 transition-all duration-500 relative rounded p-1">
                <div class="-mt-4 absolute tracking-wider px-1 uppercase text-xs">
                    
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <span class="block text-red-500">{{ $error }}</span>
                    @endforeach
                    
                    <form action="{{ route('categories.posts.store', $category) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <p>
                        <label for="title" class="bg-white text-gray-600 px-1">Titre du Post</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input id="title" autocomplete="false" tabindex="0" type="text" class="py-1 px-1 text-gray-900 outline-none block h-full w-full">
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="border focus-within:border-blue-500 focus-within:text-blue-500 transition-all duration-500 relative rounded p-1">
                <div class="-mt-4 absolute tracking-wider px-1 uppercase text-xs">
                    <p>
                        <label for="image" value="Image du post" class="bg-white text-gray-600 px-1">Contenu du post</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" autocomplete="false" tabindex="0" type="text" class="py-1 px-1 outline-none block h-full w-full">
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="border focus-within:border-blue-500 focus-within:text-blue-500 transition-all duration-500 relative rounded p-1">
                <div class="-mt-4 absolute tracking-wider px-1 uppercase text-xs">
                    <p>
                        <label for="Content" class="bg-white text-gray-600 px-1">Contenu du post</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
                    <p>
                        <textarea id="content" name="content"
                        rows="4"
                        class="ring-1 ring-gray-300 w-full rounded-md px-4 py-2 mt-2 outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-teal-300"
                        ></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="border-t mt-6 pt-3">
                        <button class="rounded text-white px-3 py-1 bg-green-500 hover:shadow-inner hover:bg-green-700 transition-all duration-300">
                            Créer mon post
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get a nice error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Comment: what do you mean by data don't pass. pass where to the controller?

Comment: My controller is ok, the problem is in the view : create.blade.php

Comment: When i change the design the form does'nt work

Comment: If you mean your form is not summiting it's maybe you haven't added type submit to the button.

Comment: Impossible, I tried with the same button, the result is the same...

Comment: You said you are getting error in your question and now saying form not working can you please expalin the problem

Comment: When I use the first form the data is transcribed in bdd, when I use the second form I get this error (see the next com) and I don't understand why the first one works and the second one no.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, `image`, `category_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, fsdfsfdsf, posts/HVJ99KjytYqMqyhlm30pnjEQdrAcFQPZy1OoElpL.png, 2, 2, 2021-12-30 17:23:06, 2021-12-30 17:23:06))

Answer (score 1):

Please add the name attribute to your title input.

```
<input id="title" name="title" autocomplete="false" tabindex="0" type="text" class="py-1 px-1 text-gray-900 outline-none block h-full w-full">
```

Comment: Oh my god, by modifying, I removed the attribute ... I spent 3 hours looking elsewhere ... Thanks for your help! :) That works